# Readable row key cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We are investigating migrating a system from a RDBMS to Cassandra and are having trouble finding a way to convert auto-increment column to Cassandra. We actually have no need for this to be sequential at all, it can even contain characters, but it must be short (ideally under 8 chars) and globally unique. Ideal value would look something like

AB123456

First part of the question is should we be generating this key in application code or in Cassandra?

Second part:
If Cassandra, how?

If Application code, is it an acceptable pattern to generate a candidate code then attempt an insert, if collision occurs then regenerate key candidate and retry?

Answer (score 1):

The common way to do this in Cassandra is to use a uuid (or timeuuid if the IDs should be time ordered).  But these must be long to get uniqueness - they are 16 bytes long.  (uuids are unique because the probability of a collision is so low; timeuuids are guaranteed unique since they contain information about the generating host and include time.)

If you need a shorter key, you can't reliably find collisions by checking before inserting.  There will always be race conditions where this will fail without external coordination.  Coming in Cassandra 2.0 is compare-and-set which will let you do this, but at a performance cost.

If you use a random 8 character string, containing only numbers and letters, there are 36^8 possible keys, with collisions becoming very likely after about sqrt(36^8) ~ 1 million operations.  You can improve this by using any character, so there are 256^8 keys, with collisions likely after about sqrt(256^8) ~ 4 billion operations.  This is probably too low though, so it would be better to use longer IDs.